# npm script with just ts-node fails

Tags: ts-node, npm-run

I have a seemingly simple npm script that is failing but I cannot seem to figure out why. 
I have the following packages installed globally:

```
+-- ts-node@8.3.0
+-- tsconfig-paths@3.8.0
+-- typeorm-model-generator@0.3.4
`-- typescript@3.5.2
```

When I run `ts-node` from the command line it runs as expected.

In my `package.json` file I have:

```
"scripts": {
    "ts_test": "ts-node"
},
```

When I run `npm run ts_test` I get the following error:

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token } in JSON at position 581
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at parse (...\node_modules\tsconfig\src\tsconfig.ts:195:15)
    at readFileSync (...\node_modules\tsconfig\src\tsconfig.ts:181:10)
    at Object.loadSync (...\node_modules\tsconfig\src\tsconfig.ts:151:18)
    at readConfig (...\node_modules\ts-node\src\index.ts:425:18)
    at Object.register (...\node_modules\ts-node\src\index.ts:189:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (...\node_modules\ts-node\src\_bin.ts:140:17)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:721:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:732:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:620:32)
```

Any advice on what could cause this error or how to further debug it would be helpful.

Update: 
Below is my tsconfig file:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "lib": [
      "es2017"
    ],    
    "baseUrl": "/",
    "noImplicitReturns": true,
    "noImplicitThis": true,
    "strictNullChecks": true,
    "strictPropertyInitialization": false,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "target": "es2017",
    "outDir": "lib",
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    /* Enables emit interoperability between CommonJS and ES Modules via creation of namespace objects for all imports. Implies 'allowSyntheticDefaultImports'. */
    "esModuleInterop": true,
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules"
  ]
}
```

Comment: please post your full tsconfig.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

JSON specification doesn't support trailing commas.  Parsing of your `tsconfig.json` is failing because of that.  Change your `tsconfig.json` to

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "lib": [
      "es2017"
    ],    
    "baseUrl": "/",
    "noImplicitReturns": true,
    "noImplicitThis": true,
    "strictNullChecks": true,
    "strictPropertyInitialization": false,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "target": "es2017",
    "outDir": "lib",
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules"
  ]
}
```

Comment: Well...that was embarrassing

Comment: WTF. I spent 6 hours looking for that issue. Thanks.